# Help creating of a test class for a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, code-coverage

I have this trigger to add points when the status of a Lead changes

```
trigger ModifiedStatus_PhotoLead on Lead (before update) {

List<Lead> lead = Trigger.new;
List<User> myUsers = [SELECT Id, PhotoLead_Points__c FROM User WHERE Id=:userinfo.getuserId()];
List<User> updatedUsers = new List<User>();

for (Lead l : lead)
{
    if (l.Status == 'Contacted')
    {
        for (User u : myUsers)
        {
            u.PhotoLead_Points__c += 10;
            updatedUsers.add(u);
        }
    }
    else if (l.Status == 'Future Follow Up')
    {
        for (User u : myUsers)
        {
            u.PhotoLead_Points__c += 25;
            updatedUsers.add(u);
        }
    }
    else if (l.Status == 'Qualified')
    {    
        for (User u : myUsers)
        {
            u.PhotoLead_Points__c += 50;
            updatedUsers.add(u);
        }

        List<ContentDocument> myFeed = [SELECT LatestPublishedVersionId FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id In (SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:l.PhotoLead_Image__c)];
        delete myFeed;
    }
}
update updatedUsers;
}
```

Can you please help me with to make an apex test class for this code ? I tried to develop it but I'm still with 0% code coverage.

Thanks !

Edit :

I tried this and now I have 47% code coverage :

```
@isTest 
public class ModifiedStatusLeadTest
{
static testMethod void testMethod1() 
{
    Lead newLead = new Lead() ;
    newLead.FirstName = 'Cole';
    newLead.LastName = 'Swain';
    newLead.Company = 'BlueWave';
    newLead.Status = 'contacted';
    insert newLead;

    try
    {
        Delete  newLead;
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {}
}
}
```

Comment: Then what have you tried?

Comment: I try this :

@isTest 
public class ModifiedStatusLeadTest 
{
    static testMethod void testMethod1() 
    {
        Lead newLead = new Lead() ;
        newLead.FirstName = 'Cole';
        newLead.LastName = 'Swain';
        newLead.Company = 'BlueWave';
        newLead.Status = 'contacted';
        insert newLead;
        
        try
        {
            Delete  newLead;
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {}
    }
}

Now, I have 47% code coverage.

Comment: Edit your question rather than putting this in comments, it will make it easier for people to read and thus to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update lead record in tes method to enter all the criterias in your trigger. Try this code.

```
@isTest public class ModifiedStatusLeadTest { 
    static testMethod void testMethod1() { 
        Lead newLead = new Lead() ; 
        newLead.FirstName = 'Cole'; 
        newLead.LastName = 'Swain'; 
        newLead.Company = 'BlueWave'; 
        newLead.Status = 'contacted'; 
        insert newLead; 
        update newLead;

        newLead.Status = 'Future Follow Up';
        update newLead;

        Integer points = [SELECT Id, PhotoLead_Points__c FROM User WHERE Id=:userinfo.getuserId()][0].PhotoLead_Points__c;
        newLead.Status = 'Qualified';
        update newLead;
        //Assert if PhotoLead_Points__c field has changed
        System.asertNotEquals([SELECT Id, PhotoLead_Points__c FROM User WHERE Id=:userinfo.getuserId()][0].PhotoLead_Points__c, points);
        try { 
            Delete newLead; 
        } 
        catch(Exception ee) {}
    } 
}
```